# Cannot login with mongodb from express js

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I am trying to connect to mongodb from node js express framework..

```
MongoClient.connect("mongodb://username:password@remote_ip:22/database_name", 

 { useNewUrlParser: true },
 function(err, database) {
  if(err) return console.error(err);

  db = database;

})
```

I got this error, I don't understand what does this mean

```
{ err: 'socketHandler',
  trace: '',
  bin: undefined,
  parseState: 
   { sizeOfMessage: 759714643,
     bytesRead: undefined,
     stubBuffer: undefined 
} }
```

is it authentication error? what does it mean?

Answer (score 0):

you are using port 22 to connect to MongoDB.
try default port 27017 instead or check on which port MongoDB is running.

```
MongoClient.connect("mongodb://username:password@remote_ip:27017/database_name", 

     { useNewUrlParser: true },
     function(err, database) {
      if(err) return console.error(err);

      db = database;

    })
```